# Скрол в table

Tags: html, вёрстка, javascript

есть таблица:

```
 <table style="width: 270px; height: 100%; display: table; overflow: scroll;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td valign="bottom" id="periubor">
                    <div style="width: 100%; height: auto; float: left; margin: 0 0 10px;">
                        <img width="40" height="40" src="image/user.png" style="float: left;">
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px; float: right; margin: 0 0 5px; font-size: 14px; color: rgba(140,190,50,.9);">
                            kirpich634@gmail.com
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: auto; float: right; color: rgba(70,70,70,.9);">
                            esr
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="width: 100%; height: auto; float: left; margin: 0 0 10px;">
                        <img width="40" height="40" src="image/user.png" style="float: left;">
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px; float: right; margin: 0 0 5px; font-size: 14px; color: rgba(140,190,50,.9);">
                            kirpich634@gmail.com
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: auto; float: right; color: rgba(70,70,70,.9);">
                            esr
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="width: 100%; height: auto; float: left; margin: 0 0 10px;">
                        <img width="40" height="40" src="image/user.png" style="float: left;">
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px; float: right; margin: 0 0 5px; font-size: 14px; color: rgba(140,190,50,.9);">
                            kirpich634@gmail.com
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: auto; float: right; color: rgba(70,70,70,.9);">
                            всем привет
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="width: 100%; height: auto; float: left; margin: 0 0 10px;">
                        <img width="40" height="40" src="image/user.png" style="float: left;">
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px; float: right; margin: 0 0 5px; font-size: 14px; color: rgba(140,190,50,.9);">
                            kirpich634@gmail.com
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: auto; float: right; color: rgba(70,70,70,.9);">
                            тох
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="width: 100%; height: auto; float: left; margin: 0 0 10px;">
                        <img width="40" height="40" src="image/user.png" style="float: left;">
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px; float: right; margin: 0 0 5px; font-size: 14px; color: rgba(140,190,50,.9);">
                            kirpich634@gmail.com
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: auto; float: right; color: rgba(70,70,70,.9);">
                            dfgdfg
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="width: 100%; height: auto; float: left; margin: 0 0 10px;">
                        <img width="40" height="40" src="image/user.png" style="float: left;">
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px; float: right; margin: 0 0 5px; font-size: 14px; color: rgba(140,190,50,.9);">
                            kirpich634@gmail.com
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: auto; float: right; color: rgba(70,70,70,.9);">
                            вапвап
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="width: 100%; height: auto; float: left; margin: 0 0 10px;">
                        <img width="40" height="40" src="image/user.png" style="float: left;">
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px; float: right; margin: 0 0 5px; font-size: 14px; color: rgba(140,190,50,.9);">
                            kirpich634@gmail.com
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: auto; float: right; color: rgba(70,70,70,.9);">
                            ар
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="width: 100%; height: auto; float: left; margin: 0 0 10px;">
                        <img width="40" height="40" src="image/user.png" style="float: left;">
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px; float: right; margin: 0 0 5px; font-size: 14px; color: rgba(140,190,50,.9);">
                            kirpich634@gmail.com
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: auto; float: right; color: rgba(70,70,70,.9);">
                            рапр
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="width: 100%; height: auto; float: left; margin: 0 0 10px;">
                        <img width="40" height="40" src="image/user.png" style="float: left;">
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px; float: right; margin: 0 0 5px; font-size: 14px; color: rgba(140,190,50,.9);">
                            kirpich634@gmail.com
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: auto; float: right; color: rgba(70,70,70,.9);">
                            апрпавр
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="width: 100%; height: auto; float: left; margin: 0 0 10px;">
                        <img width="40" height="40" src="image/user.png" style="float: left;">
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px; float: right; margin: 0 0 5px; font-size: 14px; color: rgba(140,190,50,.9);">
                            kirpich634@gmail.com
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: auto; float: right; color: rgba(70,70,70,.9);">
                            впарвпар
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="width: 100%; height: auto; float: left; margin: 0 0 10px;">
                        <img width="40" height="40" src="image/user.png" style="float: left;">
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px; float: right; margin: 0 0 5px; font-size: 14px; color: rgba(140,190,50,.9);">
                            kirpich634@gmail.com
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: auto; float: right; color: rgba(70,70,70,.9);">
                            впар
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="width: 100%; height: auto; float: left; margin: 0 0 10px;">
                        <img width="40" height="40" src="image/user.png" style="float: left;">
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px; float: right; margin: 0 0 5px; font-size: 14px; color: rgba(140,190,50,.9);">
                            kirpich634@gmail.com
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: auto; float: right; color: rgba(70,70,70,.9);">
                            пар
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="width: 100%; height: auto; float: left; margin: 0 0 10px;">
                        <img width="40" height="40" src="image/user.png" style="float: left;">
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px; float: right; margin: 0 0 5px; font-size: 14px; color: rgba(140,190,50,.9);">
                            kirpich634@gmail.com
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: auto; float: right; color: rgba(70,70,70,.9);">
                            впавп
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 100%; height: auto; float: left; margin: 0 0 10px;">
                        <img width="40" height="40" src="image/user.png" style="float: left;">
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px; float: right; margin: 0 0 5px; font-size: 14px; color: rgba(140,190,50,.9);">
                            kirpich634@gmail.com
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 235px; height: auto; float: right; color: rgba(70,70,70,.9);">
                            чвапвыарвыара
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
```

необходимо чтобы таблица не растягивалась по содержимому, а выводился скрол бар и при загрузке страницы содержимое

```
<td>
</td>
```

выводилось начиная снизу а не сверху/

Comment: я пробовал display: block; тагда таблица не растягивается ,но скрол не работает.

Answer (score 2):

заверните в `<div style='overflow:auto;height:высота в px или в %'></div>`

> выводилось начиная снизу а не сверху

целесообразнее развернуть на серверной стороне.

Answer (score 0):

Замените height: 100% на min-height: 150px например.

Comment: да не непашет вроде:(

Answer (score 0):

вообщето

```
max-height: <размер>px; overflow:auto;
```

и еще, не надо в каждом диве задавать стиль... запаритесь менять если что. используйте `css`

Answer (score 0):

ужас, есть способ лучше, переписать все с нуля и использовать блоки вместо таблиц, вместо атрибутов использовать css

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .page {
            width: 270px;
            height: 99%;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            border: 1px solid #454545;
        }
        .post{
            width: 235px;
            margin: 0 0 5px;
            font-size: 14px;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 0 10px;
        }
        .post img{
            float: left;
        }
        user{
            color: rgba(140,190,50,.9);
        }
        .text{
            width: 235px;
            height: auto;
            float: right;
            color: rgba(70,70,70,.9);
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
          <div class="post">
            <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/be07a9fd5fc86f541b713e7a460d019b?s=32&d=identicon&r=g">
            <div class="user">
              kirpich634@gmail.com
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              Text
            </div>
          </div><div class="post">
            <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/be07a9fd5fc86f541b713e7a460d019b?s=32&d=identicon&r=g">
            <div class="user">
              kirpich634@gmail.com
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              Text
            </div>
          </div><div class="post">
            <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/be07a9fd5fc86f541b713e7a460d019b?s=32&d=identicon&r=g">
            <div class="user">
              kirpich634@gmail.com
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              Text
            </div>
          </div><div class="post">
            <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/be07a9fd5fc86f541b713e7a460d019b?s=32&d=identicon&r=g">
            <div class="user">
              kirpich634@gmail.com
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              Text
            </div>
          </div><div class="post">
            <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/be07a9fd5fc86f541b713e7a460d019b?s=32&d=identicon&r=g">
            <div class="user">
              kirpich634@gmail.com
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              Text
            </div>
          </div><div class="post">
            <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/be07a9fd5fc86f541b713e7a460d019b?s=32&d=identicon&r=g">
            <div class="user">
              kirpich634@gmail.com
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              Text
            </div>
          </div><div class="post">
            <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/be07a9fd5fc86f541b713e7a460d019b?s=32&d=identicon&r=g">
            <div class="user">
              kirpich634@gmail.com
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              Text
            </div>
          </div><div class="post">
            <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/be07a9fd5fc86f541b713e7a460d019b?s=32&d=identicon&r=g">
            <div class="user">
              kirpich634@gmail.com
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              Text
            </div>
          </div><div class="post">
            <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/be07a9fd5fc86f541b713e7a460d019b?s=32&d=identicon&r=g">
            <div class="user">
              kirpich634@gmail.com
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              Text
            </div>
          </div><div class="post">
            <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/be07a9fd5fc86f541b713e7a460d019b?s=32&d=identicon&r=g">
            <div class="user">
              kirpich634@gmail.com
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              Text
            </div>
          </div><div class="post">
            <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/be07a9fd5fc86f541b713e7a460d019b?s=32&d=identicon&r=g">
            <div class="user">
              kirpich634@gmail.com
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              Text
            </div>
          </div><div class="post">
            <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/be07a9fd5fc86f541b713e7a460d019b?s=32&d=identicon&r=g">
            <div class="user">
              kirpich634@gmail.com
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              Text
            </div>
          </div><div class="post">
            <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/be07a9fd5fc86f541b713e7a460d019b?s=32&d=identicon&r=g">
            <div class="user">
              kirpich634@gmail.com
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              Text
            </div>
          </div><div class="post">
            <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/be07a9fd5fc86f541b713e7a460d019b?s=32&d=identicon&r=g">
            <div class="user">
              kirpich634@gmail.com
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              Text
            </div>
          </div><div class="post">
            <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/be07a9fd5fc86f541b713e7a460d019b?s=32&d=identicon&r=g">
            <div class="user">
              kirpich634@gmail.com
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              Text
            </div>
          </div><div class="post">
            <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/be07a9fd5fc86f541b713e7a460d019b?s=32&d=identicon&r=g">
            <div class="user">
              kirpich634@gmail.com
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              Text
            </div>
          </div><div class="post">
            <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/be07a9fd5fc86f541b713e7a460d019b?s=32&d=identicon&r=g">
            <div class="user">
              kirpich634@gmail.com
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              Text
            </div>
          </div><div class="post">
            <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/be07a9fd5fc86f541b713e7a460d019b?s=32&d=identicon&r=g">
            <div class="user">
              kirpich634@gmail.com
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              Text
            </div>
          </div><div class="post">
            <img src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/be07a9fd5fc86f541b713e7a460d019b?s=32&d=identicon&r=g">
            <div class="user">
              kirpich634@gmail.com
            </div>
            <div class="text">
              Text
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ААА! Зачем все это постить?

Comment: @KaZaца Каков вопрос, таков ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Таблицу загоняешь в div с атрибутами CSS overflow по иксу. И все.